# How to back up the configuration of an Enterasys C2G 124-24 switch via TFTP

Tags: tftp

I want to back up the configuration of an Enterasys switch via TFTP. When I connect a machine to the switch and give it the command, it returns the error:

```
please remove back up file
```

How I can back it up?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try deleting the backup file? I haven't used an Enterasys before but a quick search of your problem yielded a manual explaining what you're trying to do and how to fix it.

http://www.manualslib.com/manual/441038/Enterasys-C5g124-24.html?page=92

Answer (score 1):

```
A4(su)->show config outfile configs/config-bak.cfg
A4(su)->copy configs/config-bak.cfg tftp://<IP_ADDRESS>/config-bak.txt
```

Please post the commands you used to back up the configuration. If it is not a command issue you might want to check your tftp server. Is it reachable? Can you upload files from other sources? (if not - check windows firewall & reachability between switch an TFTP server)